# ngbDropdownToggle doesn't show as active

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using ng-Bootstrap, and have a `nav` as my `navbar`. Basically I don't know if I am using the correct component (nav for navbar), if so, I have issues for indicating the `active` tab. I mean, when a link is active, then a dropdown link is clicked, the previous Non-dropdown link is still shown as active. I don't know if I am clear...

as you see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LjTK.png) the url is not Home. but the link is still indicated as Active

Comment: can you make a reproducible example in stackblitz?

Comment: @CaioOliveira since i'm using the ngBootstrap package , i think i can't create a stackblitz project